# Static functions or Events in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, events, static-methods

I'm working with an application which was originally designed to make heavy use of static-variables and functions to impose singleton-style access to objects.  I've been utilizing Parsley to break apart some of the coupling in this project, and I'd like to start chiseling away at the use of static functions.

I will explain the basic architecture first, and then I'll ask my questions.

Within this application exists a static utility which sends/receives HTTP requests.  When a component wishes to request data via HTTP, it invokes a static function in this class:

```
Utility.fetchUrl(url, parameters, successHandler, errorHandler);
```

This function calls another static function in a tracking component which monitors how long requests take, how many are sent, etc.  The invocation looks very similar in the utility class:

```
public static function fetchUrl( ... ):void {
    Tracker.startTracking(url, new Date());
    ...
    Tracker.stopTracking(url, new Date());
}
```

Any components in this application wishing to dispatch an HTTP request must do so via the web utility class.  This creates quite a bit of coupling between this class and other components, and is just one example of several where such reliance on static functions exists.  This causes problems when we're extending and refactoring the system: I would like to decouple this using events.

Ultimately, I'd like each component to instantiate a custom event which is dispatched to a high-level framework.  From there, the framework itself would relay the event to the correct location.  In other words, those components which need to perform an HTTP request would dispatch an event like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new WebRequestEvent(url, parameters, successHandler, errorHandler));
```

From there, Parsley (or another framework) would make sure the event is sent to the correct location which could handle the functionality and perform whatever is necessary.  This would also allow me a stepping-stone to introducing a more compartmentalized MVC architecture, where web request results are handled by models, injected by the framework into their own respective views.

I'd like to do the same with the tracking functionality.

Are there drawbacks from using an event-based mechanism, coupled with a framework like Parsley?  Is it better to stick with static functions/variables and use the singleton-style access?  If so, why?  Will this end up causing more trouble in the future than it's worth?

Comment: I would definitely go with Events and use a Command Pattern architecture for web requests. Fire an event -> create a command object -> execute. Command object instance will handle request and results as well as fault events.
This is quite easy to implement, I will write up a full answer in a bit.

Comment: I agree with Ian in that using some sort of MVC in which you have a controller responsible for capturing events and executing corresponding commands or command chains is a good way to go.  I don't think avoiding singletons or static methods just for the sake of it helps you necessarily though.  Further I've seen cases where things get messy using MVC frameworks when it comes to Flex modules, so certainly do your homework if you plan to make heavy use of modules.  Cairngorm works but you end up with lots of unnecessary Event classes, luckily someone built one in-house at my work, much nicer.

Comment: The real question you should be asking is: "what problem am I trying to solve by changing to Events?". Have you hit some limitation in the architecture or are you just trying to make the code cleaner? There is nothing inherently wrong with statics/singletons.

Comment: @Glenn, I've already answered that question: "Any components in this application wishing to dispatch an HTTP request must do so via the web utility class. This creates quite a bit of coupling between this class and other components, and is just one example of several where such reliance on static functions exists. I would like to decouple this using events." I've never implied anything was wrong with singletons or statics, just that this implementation creates tight-coupling across the application which is causing problems with extensions and refactoring.

Comment: I guess the "problems with extensions and refactoring" is what I considered missing. I tend to want to rewrite/refactor overzealously so I just make sure to compare benefits/drawbacks first.

Comment: @Glenn, fair enough -- I can make my response a little clearer as far as what the problem is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, short answer on Events drawbacks:

1. Slightly more weight on the system to use the events. Listeners, bubbling, capture, etc.. all have to be managed by the system. Much less of an issue when you're outside the display hierarchy, but still more expensive than straight functions. (then again, avoid pre-optimization, so get it right, then get it fast).
2. "Soft" circular dependencies can occur in complicated asynchronous systems. This means you end up with a case where A triggers an event. B notices A has changed, so updates C. C triggers an event. D notices C has changed and updates A. Doesn't usually max the CPU, but is still a non-terminating loop.
3. Sometimes you need to have forced buffering / locking of functions. Say component A and B both trigger the same event. You might not want C to be triggered twice (e.g., fetching new data from server) so you have to make sure C is marked as "busy" or something.

From personal experience, I haven't seen any other issues with event systems. I'm using the PureMVC framework in a relatively complicated system without issue.

Good luck.